# mod_rewrite 404's on Snow Leopard

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, osx-snow-leopard

My vhost:

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?id=$1&v=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My urls look like this

```
http://hatchpass.local/?id=fbb43&v=minimal
```

mod_rewrite is enabled in Apache and I've confirmed it *is* loading, however, when I try something like http://hatchpass.local/fbb43 I get 404'd.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression in your `RewriteRule` matches `foo/bar`. The URL ("http://hatchpass.local/fbb43") doesn't apply to that. It's simply incoming as "fbb43".

Comment: Ah! Of course. v is an optional parameter and so I never tested with it, but I included it in the condition. The rule should be: RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?id=$1 [L] And that works :)